# how can i solve this error in my win32 reading image file code

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I couldnt solve this problem. I dont know why im getting this error message.

> Exception thrown at 0x7642DEB5 (KernelBase.dll) in Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Error at `ReadFile(file,lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead-1, NULL, NULL)`

Here my code. I am trying to access a JPG file to read its header.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    LPCTSTR path = "jpg.jpg";
    DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead;

    HANDLE file = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "The file couldnt be opened" << std::endl;
    }

    nNumberOfBytesToRead = GetFileSize(file, NULL);

    BYTE *lpBuffer = new BYTE[nNumberOfBytesToRead-1] ;

    if (ReadFile(file,lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead-1, NULL, NULL))
    {
        delete[] lpBuffer;
        CloseHandle(file);
        std::cout << "The file couldnt be read" << std::endl;
    }
    CloseHandle(file);
    delete[] lpBuffer;

    if (file != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "The file has been closed" << std::endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you i have solved this problem. I have an another problem

> lpBuffer = 0xcccccccc Error reading characters of string.>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqqty.jpg)

Here my new code.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
LPCTSTR path = "jpg.jpg";
DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead = 0;
DWORD nNumberOfBytesRead = 0;
HANDLE file = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    std::cout << "The file couldnt be opened" << std::endl;
}

nNumberOfBytesToRead = GetFileSize(file, NULL);

BYTE *lpBuffer = new BYTE[nNumberOfBytesToRead];

if (ReadFile(file, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, &nNumberOfBytesRead, NULL))
{
    std::cout << "The file couldnt be read" << std::endl;
}

CancelIo(file);
CloseHandle(file);
delete[] lpBuffer;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from `nNumberOfBytesToRead`? You should not be doing that, you are ignoring the last byte in the file. Also, if `ReadFile()` fails, you have a double-delete error. You are not exiting from `main()` if any error occurs, you keep going and cause more errors. And `if (file != 0)` will always be true since `hFile` is never 0 at that point in the code. `CloseHandle()` does not modify the value of the `HANDLE` it closes. That is why it has a `BOOL` return value instead.

Comment: Rather than using `ReadFile()` to manually read a *copy* of the file into memory, consider using `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` to map the original file directly into memory.

Comment: You call CloseHandle twice on the same handle, which might be invalid.

Comment: *lpBuffer = 0xcccccccc Error reading characters of string* - and so what ? `CancelIo(file);` - senseless call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the Access Violation is due to memory address 0x00000000 being written to.

This is because you are passing a NULL pointer to the `lpNumberOfBytesRead` parameter of `ReadFile()`.

Per the [`ReadFile()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx):

> lpNumberOfBytesRead [out, optional]
>
> A pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes read when using a synchronous `hFile` parameter. **`ReadFile` sets this value to zero before doing any work or error checking**. Use `NULL` for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results.
>
> **This parameter can be NULL only when the `lpOverlapped` parameter is not NULL.**

You are passing `NULL` to `lpOverlapped`, so you CANNOT pass NULL to `lpNumberOfBytesRead`.  You MUST pass a pointer to an allocated `DWORD` to receive the number of bytes actually read, eg:

```
DWORD nNumberOfBytesRead;
...
if (ReadFile(file, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead-1, &nNumberOfBytesRead, NULL))
```